# How to divide a texture to tiles and show border for each tile in webgl/opengl?

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, twgl.js

I am trying to work on a application that requires to split the image into dynamic x,y parts and process each part.

For example : if a image is of dimensions 500 X 800, where width is 500 and 800 is height.
I have to break the image using [32, 32] :

`xTiles = Math.ceil(500/32)=16;
  yTiles = Math.ceil(800/32)=25`

So, the number of tiles are 16 X 25 = 400. In other words, the whole image is divided into 400 parts.

Now I need to show each tile with some border and also want to separate the textures so that I can process them separately.

I am not sure where can I save those 400 tiles texture, saving it as textures will be a good solution? Or shall I save the result to a single texture with varying coordinates.

Can someone suggest the best solution possible for this kind of problem.

I am using Html5 canvas, WebGL, fabric.js, twgl.js library

Can I use framebuffer also?

Comment: It would help it you had already tried to solve the problem yourself and posted some code. Coming up with the "best solution possible" is simply outside the scope of SO.